# Logstash JDBC input, filter event timestamp different to @timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to change the `@timestamp` to match my `timestamp`, this is the time my event occurred at not when logstash time stamped it.

**here is my conf file**

```
input {
 jdbc {
   jdbc_driver_library => "C:/logstash/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"
   jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/transport"
   jdbc_user => "root"
   jdbc_password => ""
   schedule => "* * * * *"
   statement => "select id, timestamp, type, service, data, success, trans_id from audit where timestamp >= :sql_last_start"    
 }
}

filter {
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
      add_tag => [ "tsmatch" ]
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
     index => "audit-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
     document_id => "%{id}"
 }
 stdout {
     codec => rubydebug
 }  
}
```

Out put

```
{
        "id" => 32,
 "timestamp" => 2015-11-18 18:21:44 +0000,
      "type" => "Scheduled",
   "service" => "Road",
      "data" => "Changing the time",
   "success" => 1,
  "trans_id" => "ta819rsc",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2015-11-18T18:22:00.069Z",
      "tags" => [
    [0] "_dateparsefailure"
]
}
```

Elasticsearch

[image]

As can be seen, the timestamps (times) are different. This will mess up my data when I bring it into Kibana as I want the histogram to filter on when the event happened not when logstash gave it the timestamp.

Can some one provide me with the work around.

**UPDATE:**

I have changed the filter as suggested to

```
match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ" ]
```

and the times are still out, and get the same `_dateparsefailure` in response. Would it have anything to do with the fact it's a `Datestamp` from MySQL and it can't be converted?

G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I finally figure how to get the `@timestamp` to match that of the time the event happened.

I needed to format the my timestamp to string format, and I did this with the help of `DATE_FORMAT()` from [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

**MySQL** Data:

[image]

Here is **logstash** conf code.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    code omitted....
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "select id, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS timestamp, type, service, data, success, trans_id from `transport`.`audit` where timestamp >= :sql_last_start"    
  }
}

filter {
    date {
      locale => "en"
      timezone => "UTC"
      match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
       index => "audit-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
       document_id => "%{id}"
}
   stdout {
       codec => rubydebug
   }    
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
        "id" => 65,
 "timestamp" => "2015-11-19 11:28:31",
      "type" => "Scheduled",
   "service" => "Road",
      "data" => "Changing the time",
   "success" => 1,
  "trans_id" => "ee565",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2015-11-19T11:28:31.000Z"
}
```

As you can see `@timestamp` match that of event **timestamp**

**Elasticsearch** index.

[image]

I hope this help other..

G

Answer (score 1):

Note the _dateparsefailure tag in our document.

Your 'timestamp' field looks like this: 2015-11-18 18:21:44 +0000

while your date{} pattern looks like this:  YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS

They need to match.

Comment: could you suggest how I could fix?

Comment: Your data has no seconds, so lose the ",SSS" part.  You have a timezone offset, which might be matched with "ZZZ".

Comment: I did try what you said but still get the same error and timestamp still not match. `match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ" ]`

Answer (score 1):

I was exactly in the same problem, my field timestamp retrieved by the jdbc input filter was not the date filter plugin.

I think that the problem is jdbc input plugin returns a date type field whereas date filter plugin expects a string to parse.

That's why when you convert date field to string format by sql statement, it works.

I found another solution:
in your sql statement simply do

```
statement => "select id, timestamp as \"@timestamp\", type, service ..."
```

PS: \"@timestamp\" was not working with my jdbc driver Ucanassess, I've used

```
[@timestamp]
```